# Paracompactness and inner product on vector bundles

Tags: gn.general-topology, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space. It is well-known that every vector bundle on $X$ possesses a continuous inner product, provided that $X$ is paracompact.
Is the converse true? -- Namely assume that $X$ is a Hausdorff space such that every
vector bundle on $X$ has a continuous inner product, does this imply that $X$ is paracompact?

Comment: A good starting point could be the Michael selection theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem. Under your assumption, can one define a continuous selection to any lsc multimap on X with values nonempty closed convex sets of a Banach space?

Comment: What type  of vector  bundles we  should  associate to a lsc multimap on X ? Under  my  assumption can we prove a weaker result that each lsc multimap on X with valuse in finite  dimensional banach space possesses  a continuous selection?