# Which spaces have the (weak) homotopy type of compact Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Inspired by the discussion in the comments of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150226/characterization-of-compact-space-up-to-homotopy-equivalent), I'd like to ask the following question: is it possible to characterize the class of spaces that are homotopy equivalent (or weak equivalent) to compact Hausdorff spaces?  As noted in the linked question's comments, no locally connected space with infinitely many components can be homotopy equivalent to a compact Hausdorff space.  Are there any other restrictions?  Is every path-connected space homotopy equivalent to a compact Hausdorff space?  It seems plausible to me that every space might at least be weak equivalent to a compact Hausdorff space: perhaps the topology on an infinite CW-complex can be coarsened to be compact Hausdorff without changing the weak homotopy type.

Update: I've accepted Jeremy Rickard's answer, as it seems to more or less completely answer the case of weak equivalence (amazingly, every space is weak equivalent to a compact Hausdorff space iff there does not exist a measurable cardinal).  The comments indicate that spaces having the (strong) homotopy type of compact Hausdorff spaces are much more restricted; I'd still welcome answers elaborating further on this.

Comment: If you allow non-Hausdorff spaces, there are finite path-connected, non-contractible spaces (e.g., the "pseudocircle") which can't be homotopy equivalent to any Hausdorff space, since they have no non-constant continuous maps to any Hausdorff space. This doesn't answer the weak equivalence question, though, as the pseudocircle is weakly equivalent to a circle.

Comment: Ah, of course.  It would be natural to restrict to completely regular spaces, as those are the spaces with "enough" maps to compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Is a countably infinite wedge of circles homotopy equivalent (or weak equivalent) to a compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: @JulianRosen: I think so, for weak equivalence at least: take an infinite string of circles glued together like OOOOOOO... and have them shrink and oscillate like a topologist's sine curve that approaches a segment of the first circle.

Comment: The paper http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~adamp/preprints/compact/article.pdf proves that iff there are measurable cardinals then there are groups that are not the fundamental group of any compact space. I'm kind of hoping that this is a sledgehammer ...

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Wow, that's fascinating!  You should post that as a (partial) answer.  From skimming the paper, it seems like what's going on is that if $\kappa$ is measurable, it is possible to define a sort of transfinite composition of length $\kappa$ in the fundamental group of a compact space.

Comment: Igor Belegradek has answered [the other question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150226/characterization-of-compact-space-up-to-homotopy-equivalent). His answer says essentially that a CW-complex which is homotopy equivalent to a compact space must be finitely dominated. In particular, any CW-complex with non-finitely generated homology cannot be homotopy equivalent to a compact topological space.

Comment: Another related work is Watanabe's "On spaces that have the shape of compact metric spaces", see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm104/fm10411.pdf‎. It proves among other things that a compact space $X$ is shape equivalent to a compact metric space if and only if for any finite simplicial complex $P$ the set of homotopy classes of maps $X\to P$ is countable.

Comment: Since no counterexample has yet been recorded, I'll notice that the long line $\mathbb{L}$ is a path-connected Tychonoff space which is not homotopy equivalent to a compact Hausdorff space (or in fact any Lindelöf space, regardless of separation). There are two homotopy classes of self-maps of $\mathbb{L}$, one represented by the identity and the other by the class of any bounded map. Of course the same argument shows exactly why $\mathbb{L}$ has the weak homotopy type of a point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if there are measurable cardinals then it follows from the results of

A. Przeździecki, Measurable cardinals and fundamental groups of compact spaces. 
Fund. Math. 192 (2006), no. 1, 87–92.

that there are spaces not weakly equivalent to any compact Hausdorff space, as Przeździecki proves that (if and only if there is a measurable cardinal) there are groups $G$ that are not the fundamental group of any compact Hausdorff space, and so the classifying space of such a group is a counterexample.

He also proves that every group of non-measurable cardinality is the fundamental group of a path-connected compact space, answering a question of Keesling and Rudyak who had earlier proved this with "connected" in place of "path-connected" in

J.E. Keesling and Y.B. Rudyak, On fundamental groups of compact Hausdorff spaces.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 135 (2007), no. 8, 2629–2631.

Comment: I'm wondering if Przeździecki's construction of a compact path-connected space with given non-measurable fundamental group actually shows that every non-measurable space is weakly equivalent to a compact space? He starts with a CW-complex with the right fundamental group, and then iteratively takes the Stone-Čech compactification and "path-connectifies". I'm probably missing something, but it seems as though his construction might preserve higher homotopy groups.

Comment: Let me add a few references for the case of countable groups. Any countable group has non-measurable cardinality, so Przeździecki's result you quote applies. Much earlier Felt [Procedings AMS, 1974] showed that any collection of countable groups $\pi_i$ which are abelian for $i>i$ can be realized as homotopy groups of a compact metric space, and in fact, the fundamental group action on higher homotopy groups can be prescribed as well.

Comment: On the other hand, Shelah (see Pawlikowski, Proceedings AMS, 1998) showed that the fundamental group of a connected, locally connected compact metric space is finitely generated (recall that finitely generated groups are countable). It seems there is a difference between "compact metric" and "compact Hausdorff" cases. Also Virk [Realizations of countable groups as fundamental groups of compacta, Mediterr. J. Math. 10 (2013), no. 3] showed that any countable group is the fundamental group of a compact path-connected metric space. By Shelah, the space cannot be locally connected.

Comment: I've emailed Przeździecki, encouraging him to come on here to post his thoughts.

Comment: I believe you are correct that Przeździecki's construction actually preserves all homotopy groups: at each stage, up to weak equivalence, he's replacing a space $X$ with $X\vee T$ for some tree $T$.  He iterates this countably many times, takes the telescope, and then does it one more time.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Thanks for the references!  Note that it is obvious not every group can be the fundamental group of a compact metric space, since there are only continuum many of them up to isomorphism.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't think he's exactly replacing $X$ by $X \vee T$, but by a space weakly equivalent to $X \vee T$. The leaves of $T$ are in the closure of $X$, which is what makes the final space compact ... I think.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "up to weak equivalence".  You're correct that that's what makes the final space compact: it makes the telescope locally compact, so then it can be compactified in the manner of a topologist's sine curve as I indicated in my comment above.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I misread your comment. I hope Przeździecki will come on to confirm what we think. (By the way, am I the only one who's copy-and-pasting his name every time, to avoid having to spell it?)

Comment: @EricWofsey: not sure what you mean by "them". The set of isometry classes of compact metric spaces, and the set of isomorphism classes of countable groups both bijective to $\mathbb R$. My comments were only about countable groups.

Comment: Actually, it's important that he's not quite taking the telescope of the spaces $X\vee T$: rather, he's taking the telescope of their Stone-Cech compactifications (which have the weak homotopy type of $X\vee T \sqcup D$ for a discrete space $D$, but the extra components become part of the tree at the next stage of the telescope).  This is essential in order that the telescope be locally compact.  But this doesn't affect the weak homotopy type of the telescope, since any map from a compact space will still factor through a subspace of the form $X\vee T$.

Comment: Przeździecki's construction is also stated only for path-connected spaces, but I think that's not important: the only important thing to know is that if $X$ has nonmeasurable cardinality, then $\beta X$ has no nontrivial paths other than those in $X$.  This seems to follow by the exact same argument as in his Lemma 4.1 (see the reference http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501463).

Comment: I'm also quite curious about the history of this result: while Przeździecki's paper is from the past decade, it seems that all the tools needed for his telescope construction were known by around 1960, and all the tools for his counterexample assuming the existence of a measurable cardinal were known by around 1970.  Did anyone else notice these ideas earlier?

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't think it's that odd. To answer a question with existing tools, you don't only need to be proficient in using those tools ... you also need to ask (or be asked) the question.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, am I correct in concluding that Przeździecki's construction on a space $X$ is only known to be weakly equivalent to $X$ when $X$ has non-measurable cardinality?

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Yes (and in this respect, "non-measurable" means "smaller than the least measurable cardinal", rather than the negation of "measurable" as set theorists usually use the term).  When $X$ has measurable cardinality, it is possible that there are unexpected paths in any compactification of $X$ that change the homotopy type, and indeed by the first part of his paper this must happen for spaces with certain fundamental groups.

Comment: The discussion above answers everything, but since I received two email invitations... Yes the construction preserves the weak homotopy type of CW complexes of nonmeasurable cardinality. All that is used in the paper is (1) $S^1$ is path connected, even compactness of $S^1$ is not needed (2) If $X$ is a CW complex of nonmeasurable cardinality then $\beta X$ has no nontrivial paths other than those in $X$ (3) A telescope of compact spaces can be compactified without changing its weak homotopy type. -/-/- The construction can be modified so as to include disconnected CW complexes.

Comment: About history - I know only my part in it. I noticed that if any group is a fundamental group of some compact space then Vopenka cardinals can not exist (they are way above measurable cardinals). I thought that `people should know this' and sent a number of queries. Nobody seemed to know; I found a messy argument that it is not the case and dumped it. Keesling and Rudyak turned out to be more interested and published a neat proof below the first measurable cardinal. I took their method and rewrote my part. I should have mentioned the weak homotopy type but I thought nobody would be interested.